# OpenGL function need to be called twice to take effect

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, opengl

I have a QWindow which lives in one thread and then I have another class that renders on that QWindow surface from another thread.

I did call XInitThreads() in main function before anything else. I created the QOpenGLContext in that QWindow class and then moved it (moveToThread) to the render thread where I made it current. Now I'm trying to just clean the screen and set the colour, but when I call the glClear and glClearColor it gets totally ignored for the first time (no error, no crash, no nothing), I need to call it second time for that functions to take effect. Also after I call it two times it clear the screen and set the colour, but if I want to set the colour to a different one I need to do it twice again in order to take effect.

I'm swapping the buffer correctly, and I know that the first time I call the glclear* that it gets ignored, because after I swap the buffer for the first time there is a random noise on the screen window (which shouldn't be there after glclear).

Here is the initialization in the QWindow subclass:

```
void OpenGLWindow::initialize()
{
    if (!m_context) {
        m_context = new QOpenGLContext();
        m_context->setFormat(requestedFormat());
        m_context->create();
    }


    thread = new ThreadHelper(m_context, this);
    m_context->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();

}
```

And here is the rendering class:

```
ThreadHelper::ThreadHelper(QOpenGLContext *context, OpenGLWindow *window) : 
    m_context(context),
    m_window(window)
{
}


void ThreadHelper::run()
{
    m_context->makeCurrent(m_window);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

    // in order to take effect this have to be called for the second time
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

    swapOpenGLBuffers();
 }

void ThreadHelper::swapOpenGLBuffers() 
{
    m_context->swapBuffers(m_window);
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? I'm using qt5.2.1, tried this on intel and nvidia graphics and the result was the same.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glClear` will use the currently set clear color for clearing the color buffer (which is set via `glClearColor`). So your first clear call will just use the old/default clear color, the second one will have the effect you intend it to have and the additional `glClearColor` is just redundant. Just swap the order of the first two lines and remove your duplicated code.

Comment: I can't believe how stupid I am. I have read a lot about openGL and done a few project with openGL on my own, how could I done such rookie mistake? Anyway, that was the issue. Thanks